# SQL, Edit a field in a table row, entering a character at the beginning and at the end.

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need, through an **SQL query**, to **wrap** the field in a table row as follows:

field: `my-long-text`

field after update: `[:en]my-long-text[:]`

how can I move?

Comment: Do you want to update the table data, or just to adjust the selected data?

Comment: update multiple data

Comment: Then fthiella's answer below will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An UPDATE query and a CONCAT should be enough:

```
update tablename
set
  field = concat('[:en]', field, '[:]')
```

If field is null concat will return null, but you can exclude with `where field is not null` and of course if the field is already wrapped you have to exclude it somehow (but this depends on your logic).